# SQL: Having count more than X

Tags: sql

I am working on a query to extract certain parameters. For example, below SQL query returns the following result:

```
IncidentNum    Units   count
-------------------------------
19-00001912    chief    2
19-00001912    engine   5
19-00001912    other    14
```

I have over 200 incident numbers that I need to verify that each incident number has at least 2 engine and 1 chief units. The incident number used n the query is just an example.

I would like to use "Having" to extract just the chief and engine units. I'm trying to modify the query, but no success so far. Help.

```
select t.IncidentNum, t.units, count(*) as count
from (
select incidentnum, 
case 
when unit like 'E%' or unit like 'PE%' then 'engine'
when unit like 'BC%' then 'chief'
else 'others'
end as units
from unit
where unit not like 'EMS%'
) t
where t.IncidentNum in ('19-00001912') 
group by t.IncidentNum, t.units
```

Comment: Can you provide some more detail on what you are trying to do? From your question it's not clear why you can't just do WHERE units IN ('chief','engine')

Comment: I added more information. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you a list of all incident numbers that meet your requirements. (and the counts)

```
With basequery as (
  select t.IncidentNum, t.units, count(*) as count
  from (
    select incidentnum, 
    case 
      when unit like 'E%' or unit like 'PE%' then 'engine'
      when unit like 'BC%' then 'chief'
      else 'others'
      end as units
    from unit
    where unit not like 'EMS%'
  ) t
  group by t.IncidentNum, t.units
), all_inc as
(
  select distinct incidentnum from basequery
)
select xall.incidentnum, b1.count as engine_count, b2.count as chief_count 
from all_inc xall
join basequery b1 on b1.incidentnum = xall.incidentnum and b1.units = 'engine' and b1.count >= 2
join basequery b2 on b2.incidentnum = xall.incidentnum and b2.units = 'chief' and b2.count >= 1
```

Comment: I need to make sure that the incident number has at least 2 engine units and 1 chief unit.

Comment: Thanks, but there is a syntax error near the 'all'.

Comment: hmm maybe because it is a reserved word -- does changing it to xall work

Comment: Yes, it was. Once I changed it to something else, it worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
       select IncidentNum, case when 
       units like 'E%' then 'Engine' else
         'Chef' end, 
        count(*) from unit
       where IncidentNum in ('19-. 
      00001912') and units not like 'EMS%'
    group by IncidentNum, units
       Having (count(*)> =2 and units like 
       'E%' or 'PE%' ) and (count(*) >=1 and        
       units like 'BC%' );
```

Comment: I need to make sure that the query needs to verify that any incident number I use has at least 2 engine units and 1 chief unit.

Comment: He needs both to be true not  to just filter on those items.

Comment: I guess and will work in the having c lause as the superior grouping is done after clubbing the interior